# Getting error msg upon form submission: "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect"

Tags: java, spring

I'm working on a Web application developed using the Spring framework, version 3.1.0.

I have a JSP page containing a form which allows the user to select a country from a SELECT dropdown listbox. Submitting the form is supposed to run a database query and return the same JSP page which includes the form as well as an HTML table of author and institute data for the selected country.

Here's part of the code for the JSP page:

```
<c:url var="submitUrl" value="/authorsInstitutes.htm"/>
<form:form action="${submitUrl}" method="POST">
   <select id="countryCode">
      <option value="-1">-- Please Select --</option>
         <c:forEach var="country" items="${countryList}">
            <option value="${country.countryCode}">${country.countryName}</option>
         </c:forEach>
   </select>
   <input type="submit"/>
</form:form>
```

and here's the code from the controller class, for the methods that handle the 'GET' and 'POST' requests:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/authorsInstitutes", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView displayAuthorsInstitutesForm() {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("authorsInstitutes");

    List<Country> countryList = countrySrv.findAll();
    mav.addObject("countryList", countryList);

    return mav;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/authorsInstitutes", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView displayAuthorsInstitutes(
    @RequestParam(value = "countryCode") String country) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("authorsInstitutes");

    List<Country> countryList = countrySrv.findAll();
    mav.addObject("countryList", countryList);

    if (country != null && !country.trim().equals("")) {
        List<Affiliation> affiliationList = 
            affiliationSrv.getAffiliationsByCountryCode(country);
        mav.addObject("affiliationList", affiliationList);
    }

    return mav;
}
```

The 'GET' request works fine, but when I select a country and submit the form, I get a 404 error message:

> HTTP Status 400 -
>  type Status report
>  message
>   description The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect
>   ().

I'm sure it's something simple, but for the life of me, I'm just not seeing what it is that I'm doing wrong. I'd appreciate any help on resolving this, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using Firebug or any similar tool , check if `countryCode` parameter is passed to server.
Also i see request mapping is

`@RequestMapping(value = "/authorsInstitutes", method = RequestMethod.POST)`

where as request is sent to `/authorsInstitutes.htm`

Comment: Thanks for responding. Regarding your second point, there's this mapping within the application's 'web.xml' file:   
  








    <servlet-mapping>
    
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
        
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping><br/>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name><br/>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern><br/>
    </servlet-mapping><br/>

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Firebug. I looked around, and found this error message:

"NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - http://localhost:8084/ReferenceManager/authorsInstitutes.htm"

Comment: If I change the 'submitUrl' value on the JSP page, and submit, I get the following error message:

HTTP Status 404 - /ReferenceManager/authorsInstitutes

type Status report

message /ReferenceManager/authorsInstitutes

description The requested resource (/ReferenceManager/authorsInstitutes) is not available.

Comment: please change the method of form to GET(just for testing ) both in jsp and controller. and then check if parameter is passed properly in URL

Answer (score 0):

As we have a request parameter `countryCode` in the POST method mapping. The controller expects that the parameter is sent in the request. This is in the below code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/authorsInstitutes", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView displayAuthorsInstitutes(@RequestParam(value = "countryCode") String country) {
 }
```

Change the select tag in the jsp to include a name attribute like this.

```
<select id="countryCode" name="countryCode">
  <option value="-1">-- Please Select --</option>
     <c:forEach var="country" items="${countryList}">
        <option value="${country.countryCode}">${country.countryName}</option>
     </c:forEach>
</select>
<input type="submit"/>
```

This will assign the contryCode to the option selected.
Try this i hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove slash from your url in url tag, like this:

`<c:url var="submitUrl" value="authorsInstitutes.htm"/>`

if you use absolute path with slash in jsp, form will not send data.